# Android: how to align element 2 to the right of element 1 while only allowing element 2 to take up as much space as needed

Tags: android

I am trying to align two layouts horizontally but can't seem to get it working. The conditions I need are:

1. Layout 1 needs to fill up the whole width EXCEPT for the width that layout 2 requires
2. Layout 2 needs to have a width of 21dp and right / left margin of 17dp.

I can't take a picture because of my job, but here' some ascii art to illustrate what I want:

[image: Ascii wizardry]

I attempted using a dummy View between the two layouts so that I could use a relative layout, but that wasn't quite working for me..so any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: <linearLayout orientation="horizontal">
<layout2 android:width="21dp" android:margin="17dp"></layout2>
<layout1 android:toLeftOf="layout2" width="match_parent"></layout1>
</lineaLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout layout_width="match_parent">
    <Layout1 layout_width="match_parent"  layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layout2"/>
    <Layout2 id="@id/layout2" layout_width=21dp layout_alignParentRight="true" layout_marginLeft="17dp" layout_marginRight=17dp/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add in the rest of the parameters as needed

Comment: I'll give this a shot..one sec

Answer (score 0):

Try using a horizontal LinearLayout and set `android:layout_weight="1"` for layout 2. Like this layout 2 should keep it's size and layout 1 will fill the rest of the available space.